# proc import CSV SAS empty values date

Tags: csv, sas

I need to import a CSV file in SAS and it gets stuck on empty fields with a date format. My log shows this field is properly recognised as DATETIME. and ANYDTDTM40. just like other datetime fields. In The first records this field is empty and the LOG then gives a NOTE invalid data. When I enter a date in the first rows with empty fields the message moves along. So it clearly has to do with missing values. Can someone help me out?

Comment: What do you mean by "import"?  Are you using some prompting system?  Running PROC IMPORT?  Or are you just writing your own data step to read the file instead of forcing SAS to guess how to read it?  Please show the code you ran and the error message from the SAS log.

Comment: Hello Tom yes I mean PROC IMPORT

Comment: here is the code I use. (cannot share folder and filenames sorry)  :  PROC IMPORT OUT=WORK.EP008
  DATAFILE="Location\file.csv"   
 OUT=work.EP008 
 DBMS=csv 
 replace;
 delimiter=';';
 guessingrows=1500;
 GETNAMES=yes;
 run;

Comment: The Log NOTE: 
NOTE: Invalid data for WellLastChangedDate in line 2 250-250.
 My CSV is ; delimited and I took out ALL ; in all text so it did not disrupt the delimiting. If I copy the date from the first non empty field in Column WellLastChangeDate to line 2 the error message moves to line 3 etc.

Comment: What character is actually in the file at line 2 column 250?  If it is only that one character and the field is supposed to be a date then just use the data as is and ignore the message.  You cannot convert any single character into a datetime value so leaving it as missing seems fine to me.

Comment: Note there is no need to remove the delimiters from the values to create a readable delimited file. Just quote the values with delimiters (and also any value with quote characters). Both SAS and EXCEL know how to do this. If you are using some other software (Oracle?) you might have to hunt for a method that will create interpretable delimited files instead of just using a simple statement.

Comment: I cannot recreate that error with invalid text in a datetime field that is being read with ANYDTDTM informat.  Are you sure the issue is not related to the ENCODING of the file being read? If SAS is trying to interpret a file that is written using WLATIN1 (or any single byte encoding) as UTF-8 then it is possible there is a single character that will be invalid when interpreted as UTF-8 because it should be the start of a multi-byte character.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In the future please make sure to show your actual code and the log - feel free to omit the data part of the log if it's confidential information.

PROC IMPORT is a guessing procedure and guesses at types. For production processes it's not a good idea to use PROC IMPORT.

You can add the `GUESSINGROWS=MAX;` option to your code to force SAS to scan the entire file before guessing at types. This will increase the run time of the process but will likely fix your issue. Also, ensure your datetime fields are consistent and correct. If the data does has mixed date types, ie MMDDYY and DDMMYY then it can be bit of a pain to manage. Or if it has DDMMYY and SAS guesses MMDDYY (or vice versa) you'll get a bunch of errors. In that case you need to write your own data step code to read in the data. You can use the code from the log as  a starting point.

Comment: Dear Reeza, I know.... I need to discuss necessity to include a license ACCESS TO PCFILES so I do not need this workaround. It is the only datetime field. Proc content shows:  WellLastChangedDate Num 8 DATETIME. ANYDTDTM40. I cannot change it into Text format in Excel because it will then show me the number of the date.

Comment: ACCESS TO PCFILES is required for Excel files not CSV so it should not be relevant to your question. CSVs open in Excel but are text files, CSV means comma separated values in a text file. And I understand it's just one field, but you still need to fix your code.